# error 403: Your client does not have permission to get URL in python google cloud module

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, server, google-bigquery

UPTADE:
According to what our system expert told me, they fixed the problem as follows: ***v6 ips must be disabled in the operating systems they are in.***

I have a python file on the server that is scheduled to run every week. like this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
gbq_credentials = create_gc_credentials(settings)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=gbq_credentials,project=project_id)
df = client.query(sql_query).to_dataframe()

#data processing
....
```

But the file that works every week, gave an error today:

```
Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1
Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/bigquery/v2/projects/xxxx/jobs</code> from this server.
```

when I run the same file on my local computer, I didn't get any errors.

**I updated the outdated python libraries on the server**. But it didn't work. Also I get the same error on all files using the google cloud module.

What could this problem be caused by ?

Comment: We have exact same problem now. Was your server in Frankfurt affiliated with Contabo hosting?

Comment: hey @Sha i updated. Check the question.

Answer (score 4):

As Bushmaster commented, disabling IPV6 solved the issue.

I'm writing down the steps for disabling it:

```bash
sudo echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It could be for many reasons. You can consider these options:

- This error can be caused due to cache, and erasing the cache
  sometimes might help to fix it.
- You may just need to restart the server.
- You are not allowed to access the resource, or there’s an error on
  the server side.
- The owners of the web server have improperly set up permissions, and
  you’re getting denied access when you really shouldn’t be.

Or

When using the BigQuery API, you need to create the client with OAuth credentials for the user. For access with an API, this is often a Service Account identity. When you create a Service Account, that account is not automatically added a membership role to your project.
To update the users and service accounts that are members of your project, go to your project, select "Permissions" in the navigation panel, and make sure the user or service account identity you are calling with is a "Reader" on the project.

In case it is about permissions, you can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#before_you_begin) about it.

Comment: Finally the problem is solved. The server has been banned by google.

Comment: @Clegane Hey, I'm getting the same message. How did you get in touch with Google? All options for Google's assistance I see require buying a support plan.

Comment: @Clegane Can you post a response describing how you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How does the "create_gc_credentials" work? From the error message, the service account running on the server does not have the permission.

Comment: There is a  function called create_gc_credentials that I wrote. but that's not the problem. Same code running on my local computer without getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Most times, the error is related to whether a user agent's identity can be verified and/or the user agent has the required permission to access a protected service.

I got this error after sending a post request to a cloud function without the [authorisation header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization).

As an example, if a cloud function was created with `Allow unauthenticated` switched on, then the request goes through without this error.
[image]

A quick test was to generate a bearer token by running `gcloud auth print-identity-token` in cloud shell, and passing the generated token in the authorisation request header. No error!